# Can I integrate an external asset source (e.g. Adobe DAM) into Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

Has anyone implemented an integration between Marketing Cloud and an external asset source? My client manages its assets in Adobe DAM and would like to use it in Marketing Cloud instead of Content Builder.

I know you can add the link to an external image to the email but I was wondering if there's any alternative to integrate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually you can also build a 1-way sync into Marketing Cloud that would copy/delete files from Adobe's DAM solution based on the events that Adobe emits.
You would, however, need a middleman like Mulesoft to understand and handle the incoming events correctly.

2-way sync wont work because SFMC does not emit events for Content Builder. Also, you will not get a warning when you delete files in Adobe that might still be in use in SFMC, nor will you get usage stats in Adobe for the copied files. All a bit of an operational nightmare TBH.

Answer (score 1):

You could evaluate using the [Content Builder extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/content-sdk.htm),

> Content Builder includes native editors, called block widgets, used to create and edit the block's content. To give your users a customized editing experience within the Content Builder editor, you can develop custom block widgets with the Content Builder Block SDK. For example, instead of using the CKEditor WYSIWYG for HTML editing, you could use a different WYSIWYG, like QuillJS, by making a block widget for it.
>
> Custom blocks are also available in the CloudPages Content Builder editor.